# Loop through a Firebase collection and sum a field

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to loop through a firebase collection of a list of hikes to get the `'Miles'` field and add them up to get the total miles. How would I go about this?

I have tried to use `.snapshot()` but that is giving me a  `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` which is a problem.

This is the code I have tried, but `doc.data['Miles']` is not correct, but it is what I am trying to do.

```
Future<double> milesHiked() async{
      double miles = 0.0;

      var docs = Firestore.instance
        .collection(globalUserName)
        .document("Done Hikes")
        .collection("Hike List")
        .snapshots();

        docs.forEach((doc) => miles += double.parse(doc.data['Miles']));

        return miles;
}
```

[image: A Screenshot of my firebase]

Comment: data is a method on document snapshot. try doc.data()['Miles']

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I am still getting the error ```The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.```

Comment: Sure. then append getDocuments() after snapshots() (.collection("Hike List")
        .snapshots().getDocuments())

Comment: I get the error ```The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the class 'Stream'.``` However, if I delete the ```.snapshots()``` then I can not do ```docs.foreach()```

Comment: Sorry, out of my scope. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're unable to fetch `'Miles'` from the snapshot is that the DocumentSnapshot needs to be casted as a Map. Doing so should allow you to fetch using the key **'Miles'**.

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(globalUserName)
    .doc('Done Hikes')
    .collection('Hike List')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    // cast the DocumentSnapshot as a Map
    final hikeItem = element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    miles+=double.parse(hikeItem['Miles']);
});
```